# Django - Case insensitive models

Tags: django, case-insensitive

I'm learning django with the Tango with Django tutorial and I want to improve some of the settings that bother me with the current app. Currently I can register users with the same name only using different capitalisation for example: "User" and "USer". I don't want this and I would like the model for user authentication to be case insensitive. 
Thanks

views.py for register

```
def register(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    registered = False
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
        profile_form = UserProfileForm(data=request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save()
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()
            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user
            if 'picture' in request.FILES:
                profile.picture = request.FILES['picture']
            profile.save()
            registered = True
            user=authenticate(username=request.POST['username'],password=request.POST['password'])
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect("../registered/")
        else:
            print user_form.errors, profile_form.errors
    else:
        user_form = UserForm()
        profile_form = UserProfileForm()
    return render_to_response(
            'rango/register.html',
            {'user_form': user_form, 'profile_form': profile_form, 'registered': registered},
            context)
```

Comment: I am not sure how are you saving User. can you give that code in views??

Comment: this is only part of the code because I can't post so many characters and indentation is off   if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
user = user_form.save()
user.set_password(user.password)
user.save()
profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
profile.user = user
if 'picture' in request.FILES:
profile.picture = request.FILES['picture']
profile.save()
registered = True            user=authenticate(username=request.POST['username'],password=request.POST['password'])
login(request, user)
return HttpResponseRedirect("../registered/")
else:
print user_form.errors, profile_form.errors

Comment: just edit the question :)

Comment: just transform the username to lowercase/uppercase before saving and every possible check.

Comment: thanks ruddra havn't thought about that :)...now i updated with the register code view

Answer (score 0):

Well you can make a check like this:

```
 if user_form.is_valid():
      check_duplicate= User.objects.filter(username__iexact= user_form.cleaned_data['username']) 
                    # or User.objects.filter(username__icontains= user_form.cleaned_data['username']) 
      if len(check_duplicate)>0:
             raise "Duplicate username exists"
```

Details about [icontains](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#icontains) & [iexact](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#iexact)